# Create a dynamic bitset in standard C++?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, bitset

I feel like I'm just hoping that they can, but can a vector access bitset member functions?

For instance, can I do something like.

```
vector<bool> myvector;
myvector.count();
myvector.test(1);
```

If not is there anyway to make a bitset dynamically using the standard C++ libraries?

EDIT:

I want to use certain bitset functions (test, count) and want to use the constructor `bitset (unsigned long val)`.

Basically I want to create a bitset for some arbitrary `val` then do some operations with test and count. Then I want to deallocate and recreate the bitset with a decremented val. I want to keep doing this until val is less than 8.

However, it doesn't seem like creating a dynamic bitset is possible and using vector which is dynamic, means I can use some of the nice bitset functions.

Comment: What should `vector.test(1)` do?

Comment: Why don't you, hm, try it? :) hint: no, it can't.

Comment: yea I tried it... but I really really wanted to believe that you could :( damn!

Comment: The Qt framework features a QBitArray - it might better suit your needs.

Comment: If you want bitsets member functions, then use a bitset!

Comment: Why did you need it to support `::std::bitset` operations? This question has a short simple answer that isn't very helpful to people. But answering the related question that caused you to want `::std::vector<bool>` to support operations it doesn't have would likely be much more interesting.

Comment: have to use only standard C++ lib.

Comment: @moesef Why don't you implement `count` yourself, it's not hard. Also, `bitset::test` does the same thing as `vector<bool>::at`, so no work to do there anyways.

Comment: Why not just use an `int` and test for the bits with `&`? If you're using gcc, there is a count builtin that works on integers, the `__builtin_popcount` function that likely compiles down to a couple of nice assembly instructions.

Comment: Not invented here? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html

Comment: Boost is not part of Standard C++ Libraries which is part of my required solution.

Comment: `std::vector<std::bitset<1>> bitset_var;` I have this workaround from this problem. Not sure if this would help you. Just put it out there. Might help some in far future. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't actualy need a dynamic bitset. `std::bitset` is  copy-assignable so you can do:

```
const size_t size = sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT;
typedef std::bitset<size> my_bitset;

unsigned long val = 42;
my_bitset bs(val);

/* do work */

bs = my_bitset(--val); // assign with new, decremented val
```

Comment: This is *not* dynamic. `size` is known at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

I have already answered to similar questions in S.O. I would suggest [BITSCAN](https://github.com/psanse/bitscan), a framework for dynamic bitsets specially oriented for fast bitscanning. It has been tested on Linux and Windows. A comparison with STL *bitset* and Boost's *dynamic_bitset* is available [here](http://blog.biicode.com/bitscan-efficiency-at-glance/).